# Eigen values of matrix formed by column vector multiplied by row vector.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-rank

Let $u$ and $v$ be column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $A = uv^T$ that is matrix formed by column vector multiplied by row vector. 
What are all the eigen values and eigen vectors of $A$? What is the rank of $A$?

Comment: This is called a dyad. Try solving $u v^T x = \lambda x$ and note that if $\lambda \neq 0$ then such an $x$ must be a multiple of $u$.

Answer (score 2):

If one of $u$ and $v$ is zero, then $A=0$ and the case is trivial.

Suppose then $u\ne0$ and $v\ne0$. Then $A\ne0$ and has rank at most $1$ (the rank of a product can't be greater than the rank of the factors). So the rank is $1$.

Consider $x=v$; then $uv^Tv=(v^Tv)u$ by direct computation.

The other eigenvalue is $0$. Since $uv^Tx=(v^Tx)u$, you should be able to finish.